# Line graph and Eulerian graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a simple, undirected and connected graph for which every vertex has degree $r$. Prove that the line graph $G'$ of $G$ is Eulerian.

So, basically we have two options for $r$, either it is even or odd. In the case that it is even, the problem is trivial, cause according to a theorem about Eulerian graphs, we have that a graph is Eulerian iff $\forall x \in V : d(x)$ is even.

Therefore, we have that $\forall v: |\Gamma(v)|$ is even, meaning even number of edges share this vertex. So, in return we will have a line graph with even degree ($d(e), e \in E$ even), so we will have an Eulerian graph.

But what happens if $r$ is odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is even, then $G$ is Eulerian, but this doesn’t immediately tell you that $G'$ is Eulerian. What you need to show is that if every vertex of $G$ has the same degree, then every vertex of $G'$ has even degree.

It turns out that you don’t need to worry about whether $r$ is even or odd. Suppose that $e=\{u,v\}$ is an edge of $G$ and hence a vertex of $G'$; we want to show that $\deg_{G'}e$ is even. Suppose that $f=\{x,y\}$ is another edge of $G$ and vertex of $G'$; under what circumstances is $\{e,f\}$ an edge of $G'$? According to the definition of the line graph, $\{e,f\}$ is an edge of $G'$ if and only if the edges $e$ and $f$ of $G$ have a vertex in common. In other words, $G'$ has an edge between its vertices $e$ and $f$ if and only if $\{u,v\}\cap\{x,y\}\ne\varnothing$. This means that $\deg_{G'}e$ is the number of edges of $G$ (other than $e$ itself) that have $u$ or $v$ as a vertex.

- Use the fact that $\deg_Gu=\deg_G=r$ to calculate $\deg_{G'}e$ in terms of $r$; then show that the resulting number is always even.

Comment: I totally understand the upper part, but I don't understand the last part where you are telling me what do calculate. So, for example, if we have an edge with degree 5 in $G$, it means that there are 5 edges that all share a common vertex, meaning we will have 5 vertices in $G'$, and all of them will be connected with each other, giving us something like $K_5$, where the vertex degree of each will be even, am I right?

Comment: @portal: Don’t worry about what $G'$ looks like; it’s not important. You just want to count the edges of $G'$ that are incident at $e$. There’s one for each vertex of $G$ that is connected to $u$ or to $v$ by an edge other than $e$.

Comment: I know that what $G'$ looks like is not important, though it somehow helps me to visualize things (or  confused me more). What confuses me is this, if I imagine that I have an odd degree edge, let's say 5, it means in the $G'$ we will have 5 vertexes that are each connected with each other, so each vertex will have a degree of 4, meaning even. But, let's say if in $G$ our degree is 4, then in the $G'$ we will have 4 vertexes that are connected with each other, meaning that the vertex degree will be 3, meaning odd.

Comment: @portal: You’re still making it much too complicated. Don’t worry about anything except the number of vertices of $G'$ that are connected to $e$. Some of them are connected to $e$ because as edges of $G$ they share the vertex $u$ with $e$; how many of those are there? Others are connected to $e$ because as edges of $G$ they share the vertex $v$ with $e$; how many of those are there?

Comment: Well, we will have $d(v)$ number of edges that share a vertex with $v$, and likewise we will have $d(u)$ number of edges that share a vertex with $u$. Because, $d(v) = d(u) = r$, we will have in total $2r$ of such edges, which clearly is even in any case, am I right?

Comment: @portal: Not quite, because one of the edges at $u$ is $e$, and one of the edges at $v$ is also $e$. That means that there are only $r-1$ *other* edges of $G$ that meet $e$ at $u$, and $r-1$ *other* edges of $G$ that meet $e$ at $v$. Thus, the vertex $e$ of $G'$ is connected by edges to how many other vertices of $G'$? Not $2r$, but ... ?

Comment: $2r - 2$, or...?

Comment: @portal: $2r-2$ is right; and $2r-2=2(r-1)$ is even, so you’re done.

Comment: Thanks, now I have to put it in a formal proof. I'm always bad when it comes to formally proving things. xD

Comment: @portal: You’re welcome. Writing up proofs takes some practice, but it’s really just a matter of organizing the information in a way that makes the logical connections clear.